# How to find all distinct closed paths from a group of points

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, math, flex4

Is it possible to find out all possible closed paths with intersection. I have a set of points in an array. I need to process the points in the array and plot the closed areas.

This is building designing project. I know all the points (Shown as green dots in the images attached) x and y values. Here i need to know each rooms separately as shown in image2(room are labeled from 1-11). How can i find out the room's boundary points.

The points may vary this is just a sample.

http://demo.enfintech.net/BuildingImage/1.jpg

http://demo.enfintech.net/BuildingImage/2.jpg

Comment: I assume you mean a set of 'pairs of connected points'.

Comment: Thanks for your response,  i have point separetly. I can change to set of points. But how can i get the corner points to each room? I need output as set of points of each room. In the above sample i need to get 11 set of points since there are 11 rooms. I think its clear now.

Answer (score 0):

What I suggest is that since all your connections are either vertical or horizontal, you can do the following:

1. Extend all connection lines in both directions so that you end up with a matrix of small cells.
2. Initially your number of rooms shall be the number of these small cells. Number them accordingly.
3. Now for each cell, check whether the boundary with its neighbour exists or not (whether the boundary line is an actual connection line or just an extrapolation).
4. If it is just an extrapolation, then join these cells into a single cell.
5. Keep repeating this for all the cells until all extrapolated lines disappear.